# Is shelve feature available in TFS web portal

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to shelve pending changes for a document file in TFS (TFS 2015) web portal, is it possible ? If yes pls assist me.

Comment: i don't know why i got down vote and what's wrong i asked ?
if it is like this i don't like to continue (like querying) in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only shelve changes from Team Explorer or from command line currently:

- [Shelve your changes in Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=vsts#shelve-your-changes)
- [Shelve Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/shelve-command?view=vsts)